# MSAL - Refresh token expiration date

Tags: azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-platform

I developped an app with using MSAL library. I know that access token is expired after 1 hour. So we can refresh it with refresh token.(MSAL automatically refresh the access token(also the refresh token itself too) after expiration when calling `AcquireTokenSilentAsync`.)

However, when is the `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` failed becuse of the expired refresh token?

So, I want to know the refreh token expiration date(I think it should dynamically change every refresh) and expose this date to users. How can I achive this?

Answer (score 2):

MSAL doesn't expose the refresh tokens as they handle refreshing tokens automatically when you call `AcquireTokenSilentAsync`. So, it's by design.

But the `RefreshToken` is usually cached, so you can read the refresh token from the cache and try to decode it.

Comment: I can see the refresh token but I couldn't decode it.